# Android calligraphy library: set default font does not work

Tags: android, fonts, calligraphy

I did used `uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy` dependency to use fonts from asset folder, however default font is not applied to my application. I followed the guideline used in other stackoverflow question but they did not work and all solutions used same syntax I used below.

Here is my application and path to font is correct since it works using XML `fontpath` property;

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static volatile Context instance;

    public static Context get() {
        return instance;
    }
    private static App enableMultiDex;
    public static Context context;

    public App(){
        enableMultiDex=this;
    }
    public static App getEnableMultiDexApp() {
        return enableMultiDex;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        instance = getApplicationContext();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/mobilefont.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wrap the Activity Context:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Comment: I missed this part should be added to `Activity` classes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. If you update your project with **API 33** or **Android 13** add below line for calligrapgy library.

  ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
            .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                    new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/century_gothic.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(io.github.inflationx.calligraphy3.R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build())).build());
```